# But if command in excel

Tags: excel

I'm trying to tell EXCEL that 
    IF G2<>I2, THEN use [ABS((H2-F2)/SQRT(((G2^2)/C2)+((I2^2)/D2)))] to fill AE,

BUT IF L2 is BLANK, leave AE empty. I'm trying the following with no success:

```
 =IF(G2<>I2, ABS((H2-F2)/SQRT(((G2^2)/C2)+((I2^2)/D2))), L2, or(if(ISBLANK((l2))=true, "")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If L2 is blank needs to be evaluated first because if it is blank then AE2 must be blank, regardless of the values of G2 and I2.

If L2 is not blank then go on to your secondary test.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(L2),"",IF(G2<>I2,ABS((H2-F2)/SQRT(((G2^2)/C2)+((I2^2)/D2)))))
```